# C++ - Coding video game sound effects?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

I've done a bunch of research, but I can't figure out how to load a .wav file into memory and then play it.  Also, I'd like to have the capability to simultaneously play multiple loaded .wav files.

Currently, I load the .wav file into string buffer, then call:

```
PlaySound(stows(buffer).c_str(), NULL, SND_MEMORY);
```

stows() is a function I created which converts a string into a wide string.

What am I doing wrong/what could I be doing better?

EDIT:  I'm trying to use SFML now.  I followed the walkthrough [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php) to a T, but I'm getting 9 linker errors when I attempt to compile.  It doesn't matter if I use the static or dynamic dlls.

EDIT2:  I must have VS2010 32 bit.  I downloaded SFML 2.0 32 bit for VS2010 and now I'm down to 5 linker errors.  It says all of them are occurring in sfml-audio-s.lib.

EDIT3: I got it to compile!  However, it simply isn't playing anything.  I used VS to debug and confirmed that I am opening the WAV file correctly and storing it in a Sound object, but when I call the play() method, nothing happens.  Furthermore, I'm getting an unhandled exception every time I close the program.

Comment: You could be using an actual audio library.

Comment: You can use [sfml](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/audio-sounds.php)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams what actual sound library would you recommend?

Comment: I keep hearing good things about [fmod](http://www.fmod.org/), but I'm okay with GStreamer.

Comment: If possible, I'd prefer to use the built-in functions.  I found an example that looked like it should work [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/88542/).  Is it possible to do load/play wav files without using an extra library?

Comment: So I'm trying to use SFML now.  I followed the walkthrough [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-vc.php) to add it.  I am positive I added it the exact way it said.  However it is simply not compiling.  I'm getting 9 linker errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!  I ended up using direct sound.  I made a class to load and play .WAV files based on a tutorial I found [here](http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut14.html), which was immensely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably convinced that `PlaySound` isn't able of mixing two sounds playing simultaneously. You can have one sound interrupt the other, and you can make it play "in the background" while your code is doing other things (using `SND_ASYNC`), but the documentation is pretty clearly stating that "if another sound is played, the current one stops" - in the section of `SND_NOSTOP`:

> If this flag is not specified, `PlaySound` attempts to stop any sound
>   that is currently playing in the same process

(If you specify `SND_NOSTOP`, it doesn't play this sound if another one is already playing).

Link to full documentation: [`PlaySound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm afraid I don't know exactly how you create sound playing using multiple sounds simultaneously, as I've never done that on a PC (I have used hardware mixers, and I've also written code to merge two sounds from a file, but that's almost certainly not what you want)